# How to do a search in a string collection in Neo4j 3.0.3

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to Neo4j and trying some queries on the movie database example. 
I want to find all actor and movie combinations where the role name contains the word "Joe". How do I do this ?

I am able to do a query when I know the complete role name e.g. Joe Banks. The query I used for that is -

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:ACTED_IN]-(movie:Movie) 
WHERE 'Joe Banks' in (r.roles) 
RETURN p,movie,r.roles;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [list predicate function](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#query-predicates) `any`:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)<-[r:ACTED_IN]-(a:Person)
WHERE any(role in r.roles WHERE role CONTAINS "Joe")
RETURN m,r,a
```

**Edit**

For case insensitive string comparison you can use the `toLower` function:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)<-[r:ACTED_IN]-(a:Person)
WHERE any(role in r.roles WHERE toLower(role) CONTAINS toLower("joe"))
RETURN m,r,a
```

Comment: Thanks ! Can I make this search case insensitive ?

Comment: You can wrap either side of the string comparison operator with the `toLower` function.

Comment: Just keep in mind that when you use toLower() or toUpper() or similar, the query will not be able to take advantage of any indexing present on the property.